# SQL UPDATE with Replace throwing 1064 error inside replace statement

Tags: mysql, sql-update, str-replace

I have used the REPLACE Statement before with success, but for some reason, this statement keeps throwing a 1064 error?

```
UPDATE `wp_UPCP_Item_Images` SET `Item_Image_URL` = REPLACE (`Item_Image_URL`,
'http://www.salestraininganddevelopment', 'http://tilesunlimitedny')
```

but keep getting this error?

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
''http://www.salestraininganddevelopment''http://tilesunlimitedny') FROM `wp_UPC' at line 1
```

Screenshot as requested:
[mysql screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZuMW.jpg)

What am I missing, just keep staring at this statement to see if i can find it but, I am lost.
Read through all the suggested questions and cant seem to find anything that works.
Thanks a ton, Jeff

Comment: There must be something else other than this code, because I could not reproduce the error.

Comment: Please post the query exactly as you are using it, and including how you execute it (e.g. the line of code you use in php). Your error doesn't match the query (in your error message, you have `...nt''http://tilesu...` where you have a comma in your query, and the code continues with `FROM wp_UPC` while it ends after `)` in your query). I would assume you are escaping/quoting incorrectly somewhere, so MySQL is getting a different query than you think it gets.

Comment: @Solarflare I am using Phpadmin SQL tab and i noticed the same thing you did, not sure what that is about

Comment: And the SQL is exactly as above. and the space as been removed as mentioned below.

Comment: Then please add a screenshot that shows the complete command and the complete error message to exclude copy&paste errors. (This is probably the first time I prefer a screenshot to pasting the text...)

Comment: couldnt figure out how to add screenshot to comments so i edited op above.

Comment: You are trying to simulating the query. Don't do that. It is just broken. Just run the query. You can use a transaction and roll it back if you are not sure what will happen (add `start transaction;` in line 1, and `rollback;` in the last line, maybe a `select * from wp_UPCP_Item_Images` in the line before that to see some results). Another trick to check if the syntax is correct without actually running the query is to write `explain ` infront of it (so `explain update wp_UPCP_Item_Images SET...`).

Comment: "You are trying to simulating the query. Don't do that. It is just broken. Just run the query. " that was it, i ran it and it went thanks a ton, didnt know simulate was broken, or at least i wasnt using it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You are trying to simulating the query. Don't do that. It is just broken. Just run the query. " that was it, i ran it and it went thanks a ton, didnt know simulate was broken, or at least i wasnt using it correctly.

Comment: Unbelievable but true.  Simulate was throwing an error for me too (similar situation).  After battling it for half an hour I searched found this and it works fine (while simulate query fails).

Answer (score 0):

There cannot be spaces between "REPLACE" and "(".